# Is there an API available to fetch the PCI compliant resources in an Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to fetch the list of Azure resources that are PCI compliant. But didn't get a proper API for this. I have tried all the APIs available in Azure docs, but none of them are related to my requirement. I am in need of resource-level/resource-type level compliant details like the resource/resource-type is PCI compliant or not.

Thanks in advance.